# Get articulations of a graph with DFS

Tags: java, graph

I'm making an algorithm to determine the articulations of a graph. Instead of removing the edges of a vertex I prefer to don't visit that vertex because is a weighted graph.

The problem I have is that when I call `dfs(0, visited, v)` it says that the vertex 0 is also an articulation, when is not. If I change the first parameter, the vertex I pass says is an articulation.

What I got:

```
Articulations:
0
2
5
8
```

Expected:

```
Articulations:
2
5
8
```

Code:

```
private boolean isConnected(int v) {
    boolean visited[] = new boolean[numVertex];

    for (int i = 0; i < numVertex; i++)
        visited[i] = false;

    dfs(0, visited, v);

    return allVisited(visited);
}

private void dfs(int source, boolean[] visited, int v) {
    visited[source] = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < numVertex; i++)
        if (graph[source][i] != NO_EDGE && source != v && !visited[i])
            dfs(i, visited, v);

}

private boolean allVisited(boolean[] visited) {
    boolean all = true;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < visited.length && all) {
        all = visited[i];
        i++;
    }

    return all;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the case of root as being a articulation point, which goes as -
If the point is root then it should have at least 2 child for being articulation point.

You can have a look at the below link, This would give you a really good description about articulation point.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/articulation-points-or-cut-vertices-in-a-graph/